# What does [expected unqualified id] mean?

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I am trying to make Battleships in C++. I am trying to make a system to store the locations of all the ships, so they cannot overlap.

However, part of the code is giving me an **expected unqualified id **Error for seemingly no reason once I added the systems to do so. Even after reverting to an earlier version, it still does not appear to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Try Tuple, Vector or Struct for this std::vector<std::vector<std::tuple<int, int>>> coords;

/* struct Coordinate {
  int x, y;
};
struct Ship {
  vector<Coordinate> coords;
};

vector<Ship> ships;*/


int urships = 5;

/* 
for (int i = 0; i < urships; i++) {
  Ship newShip;
  ships.push_back(newShip);
}
*/


int aiships = 5;

int shipsplaced = 0;

int ur2 = 1;
int ai2 = 1;

int ur3 = 2;
int ai3 = 2;

int ur4 = 1;
int ai4 = 1;

int ur5 = 1;
int ai5 = 1;

bool D_placed = false;
bool S_placed = false;
bool B_placed = false;
bool C_placed = false;
bool valid_square = true;



char vert;
int coordx;
int coordy;
int placelength;


string urboard [10][10] = {
  {"\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A"},
{"\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A"},
{"\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A"},
{"\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A"},
{"\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A"},
{"\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A"},
{"\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A"},
{"\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A"},
{"\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A"},
{"\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A","\U0001F30A"},
};
string aiboard [10][10] = {
{"W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W"},
{"W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W"},
{"W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W"},
{"W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W"},
{"W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W"},
{"W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W"},
{"W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W"},
{"W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W"},
{"W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W"},
{"W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W"},
};



void printboard(){
  ifstream letters("letters.txt");
  string line;
 cout<<"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10";
  for (int y = 0; y<10; y++ ){
    
    cout<<endl;
    for (int x = 0; x<10; x++){
      cout<<urboard[y][x];
    }
    (getline(letters,line));
    cout<<" "<<line;
  }
  cout<<endl<<endl;
}
void verticalchange(char a){
  switch(a){
    case 'A':
    case 'a':
      coordy = 0;
      break;
    case 'B':
    case 'b':
      coordy = 1;
      break;
    case 'C':
    case 'c':
      coordy = 2;
      break;
    case 'D':
    case 'd':
      coordy = 3;
      break;
    case 'E':
    case 'e':
      coordy = 4;
      break;
    case 'F':
    case 'f':
      coordy = 5;
      break;
    case 'G':
    case 'g':
      coordy = 6;
      break;
    case 'H':
    case 'h':
      coordy = 7;
      break;
    case 'I':
    case 'i':
      coordy = 8;
      break;
    case 'J':
    case 'j':
      coordy = 9;
      break;
    default:
      cout<<"letter error\n";
      valid_square = false;
  }
  
    
}

void choosesquare(){
  
  cout<<"Please input the desired coordinates\n";
  cin>>vert;
  verticalchange(vert);
  cin>>coordx;
  if (coordx>10){
    cout<<"number error";
    valid_square = false;
  }
  
  coordx--;
}
char choose;

char dir;

char placeval = ' ';

int picksleft = 100;
void pickships(){
  
  cout<<"Which ships would you like to place? Enter your desired option below. \n1: Destroyers\n2: Submarine \n3: Battleships\n4: Carriers"<<endl;  
      
  cin>>choose;
      
      
  switch(choose){
      case'1':
      cout<<"picking destroyers\n\n\n";
      if (D_placed ==true){
        cout<<"You have already placed that ship\n\nPlease pick again\n\n";
        return;
      }
        
      picksleft = ur2;
      placelength = 2;
      cout<<picksleft;
        
  }
  switch(choose){
      case'2':
      cout<<"picking submarines\n\n\n";
        if (S_placed ==true){
          cout<<"You have already placed that ship\n\nPlease pick again\n\n";
          return;
        }
        
      picksleft = ur3;
      placelength = 3;
  }
  switch(choose){
      case'3':
      cout<<"picking battleships\n\n\n";
      if (B_placed ==true){
        cout<<"You have already placed that ship\n\nPlease pick again\n\n";
        return;
        }
      
      picksleft = ur4;
      placelength = 4;
  }
  switch(choose){
      case'4':
      cout<<"picking carriers\n\n\n";
        if (C_placed ==true){
          cout<<"You have already chosen that ship\n\nPlease pick again\n\n";
          return;
        }
        
      picksleft = ur5;
      placelength = 5;
  }
  while(picksleft > 0){
    
    cout<<"Choose the starting point of your ship. You have " <<picksleft<<" 2-segment ships left.\n";
    printboard();
    choosesquare();
    
    }
    urboard[coordy][coordx] = "❎";
    printboard();
    cout<<"now decide which direction you would like the ship to point in. Type 'u' for up, 'd' for down, l for left and 'r for right'";
    
    cin>>dir;
    for (int x = 1; x<placelength; x++){
      switch(dir){
        case 'u':
        coordy--;
        urboard[coordy][coordx] = "❎";
        printboard();
      }
    }
    for (int x = 1; x<placelength; x++){
      switch(dir){
        case 'd':
        coordy++;
        urboard[coordy][coordx] = "❎";
        printboard();
      }
    }
    for (int x = 1; x<placelength; x++){
      switch(dir){
        case 'l':
        coordx--;
        urboard[coordy][coordx] = "❎";
        printboard();
      }
    }
    for (int x = 1; x<placelength; x++){
      switch(dir){
        case 'r':
        coordx++;
        urboard[coordy][coordx] = "❎";
         printboard();
      }
    }
  picksleft--;
    

  }
  switch(placelength) {
    case 2:
      D_placed = true;
      break;
    case 3:
      S_placed = true;
      break;
    case 4:
      B_placed = true;
      break;
    case 5:
      C_placed = true;
      break;
    default:
      cout<<"testing";
  }

int main() {
  
  cout<<"Welcome to Battleships! :)"<<endl;

  cout<<"Lets's start by placing your ships!\n\n";

  printboard();

  cout<<"you have "<<urships<<" total ships, composed of "<<ur2<<" 2 segment destroyers,"<<ur3<<" 3-segment submarine(s), "<<ur4<<" 4-segment battleship(s) and "<<ur5<<" 5-segment carrier(s) that can be place anywhere on the 10-by-10 grid.\n\n";
     while (D_placed == false or S_placed == false or C_placed == false or B_placed == false ){  
    pickships();
       
  }  
  cout<<"test( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)";
  //
  //Notes: use choose+1 to firgure out the number of repeats for placement of ships
//store ships coords in external files. Upon successful hit, read position data from file and check if any segments are still standing. If no, then the ship is destroyed.
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve].  Also you should include the full error message and indicate where the error is located.

Comment: `switch (placelength)` is outside of a function. If you format your code consistently it is easier to see these issues. The repeated `switch (choose)` lines with one case each are very odd. Normally you would have one switch and multiple cases.

Comment: Extra brace here `}
  switch(placelength)` and then missing brace at the end of the same function just before `main`.

Comment: Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: You can reduce the size of `verticalchange()` by converting to upper case (`toupper`) or to lower case (`tolower`) before starting the `switch` statement.

Comment: Your program may be more efficient if you use a container of `Ship`, where `Ship` contains the ship name, location and size.  So, rather than searching the board, you would search the ship container.